# How to get valid Bit Error Rate or Rx Qual

Tags: android

I am trying to get bit Error rate by using getGthe following coding but i am always get -1 only. Do  you anybody have idea to get valid Bit Error Rate. please help to get correct value.

The code are following.

```
public class GetGsmSignalStrengthActivity extends Activity {

        TelephonyManager        Tel;
        MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Tel  = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
   }
   private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
   {
     @Override
     public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
     {
      super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
      TextView dummy1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);            
      String x,m ="";            
          x=String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmBitErrorRate());
          dummy4.setText("Bit Error      : " +x);

     }

  }
}
```

Comment: where do you set MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener = new MyPhoneStateListener (); ?

Answer (score 3):

Read this [bug report comment #4](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9271). You see that it is optional and therefore possible. It will return -1 if it isn't provided by the modem manufacturer.

Quote:

> The problem is that AT+CSQ in TS 27.007 section 8.5 is listed as optional. Therefore the modem manufacturer has the choice whether or not to provide both the signal and bit error rate using standard interfaces. So when you see -1 that means the modem people haven't implemented it.

Comment: Dear WarrentFaith, Thank you so much for your reply. Is any other possible way to get the field value.

Comment: If the hardware and/or the driver doesn't provide the information, there is no way to get it, sorry